# KO3: Pretend properties on a Kohana_ORM Model

Tags: model, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Say I have a very simple model that looks like this:

```
class Model_Person extends ORM
{
 /*
     CREATE TABLE `persons` (
   `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `date_of_birth` DATE NOT NULL,
  );
 */
}
```

Is there a way I can I add sort of a pretend property with the full name?

So that I for example could do this:

```
$person = ORM::factory('person', 7);
echo $person->fullname;
```

instead of this:

```
$person = ORM::factory('person', 7);
echo $person->firstname.' '.$person->lastname;
```

Another example could be an `is_young` property that would calculate the persons age and return true if the age was below a certain number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "magic" `__get()` method like this:

```
public function __get($column)
{
    switch($column)
    {
        case 'fullname' : 
            return $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname;

        case 'is_young' :
            // calculate persons age
    }
    return parent::__get($column);
}
```

Or you can create additional methods like `fullname()` and `age()` (seems better to me).

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing. And even though the magic __get is a bit uglier than a method, I still like to keep properties as properties and methods as methods. Maybe cause I'm used to C#... Removed the break statement. Don't need that when you have a return :)

Comment: ~offtop~ Yes, I know about `break`, but I always add it in the end of `case` - its like a little habit :) For example, if I change this method and remove `return` (for example: `$result = ...`), I can easily forget about `break`...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this solution?

```
class Model_Person extends ORM 
{
      public function fullname()
      {
           return $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname;
      }
 }

$person = ORM::factory('person', 1); 
echo $person->fullname();
```

Comment: Cause then it would be different from other properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in `application/classes/ORM.php`
(`application/classes/orm.php` for Kohana prior to 3.2):

```php
<?php
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM {
    public function __get($name) {
        $getter = 'get_' . $name;
        if (method_exists($this, $getter)) {
            return $this->$getter();
        }

        return parent::__get($name);
    }
}
```

Then you can just add a method to your model class:

```php
public function get_fullname() {
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

And be able to access it as a property.